# MVC Remote Validation With Additional bool Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am trying to use Remote Validation with an additional bool checkbox field

```
[Remote("IsStorageConnectionValid", "TenantManagement", AdditionalFields = "CreateStorage")]
public String StorageConnectionString { get; set; }
```

Validation code

```
public JsonResult IsStorageConnectionValid(string storageConnectionString, bool createStorage){
```

It works perfectly in terms of it hitting the validator. However createStorage is always true irrespective of the value of the checkbox. If I use additional fields that aren't check boxes they are supplied perfectly.

Checkbox created as standard:

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CreateStorage)
```

Is this a bug? Or am I doing it wrong?

[Fiddle Is here (Is MVC4 I think but does the same thing)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aJVTIc)

Comment: It might help for us to see the code as the browser sees it.  In other words, please post a concise example of the ***rendered*** HTML markup and JavaScript.

Comment: Added Fiddle. It does the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does appear that this is a bug when used with `@Html.CheckBoxFor`. The problem is that `CheckBoxFor` renders 2 elements, a checkbox with `value="true"` and a hidden input with `value="false"` (Unchecked checkboxes do not post back so the second hidden input ensures a value is posted back for use by the `DefaultModelBinder`)

Looking at the relevant section of the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file

```
adapters.add("remote", ["url", "type", "additionalfields"], function (options) {
  var value = {
    url: options.params.url,
    type: options.params.type || "GET",
    data: {}
  },
  prefix = getModelPrefix(options.element.name);

  $.each(splitAndTrim(options.params.additionalfields || options.element.name), function (i, fieldName) {
    var paramName = appendModelPrefix(fieldName, prefix);
    value.data[paramName] = function () {
      return $(options.form).find(":input[name='" + escapeAttributeValue(paramName) + "']").val();
    };
  });

  setValidationValues(options, "remote", value);
});
```

the `return` statement returns (in your case) `.find(':input[name="CreateStorage"]').val();` which returns the value of the **first** input with the `name="CreateStorage"` which will always be `true` (the value of the checkbox)

As a test, if you render the value using `HiddenFor` rather that `CheckBoxFor` you will receive the correct value in your `IsStorageConnectionValid` method (but of course this does help since you cant change the value)

Not sure of the best solution, but the `unobtrusive` script should be first checking if `.find(..)` returns more than one element, then if the first is a checkbox which is unchecked, returning the value of the second element.

**Edit**

I have reported this as an [issue at Codeplex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2155)

**Edit 2**

I have been advised the the issue has now been [fixed here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/8aee6c29e69a32234663377b8cbb0e8fda5da76e)