# Parameters binding in remote validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a typical master details view and I need to perform remote validation on the `Name` property of my `BarViewModel`.

My view models:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
     public IEnumerable<BarViewModel> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class BarViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("CheckName", "Foo")]
    public string Name { get; set }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class FooController
{
     public ActionResult Edit()
     {
          var viewModel = new FooViewModel
          { 
              Bars = new List<BarViewModel> { new BarViewModel() } 
          };
          return View(viewModel);
     }

     // For remote validation
     public ActionResult CheckName(/*[Bind(Prefix = "???")] */string name)
     {
          // Parameter binding failed
     }
}
```

`FooViewModel` Edit view:

```
@model FooViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bars)
}
```

`BarViewmodel` EditorTemplate:

```
@model BarViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @HtmlValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when `BarViewModel.Name` is submitted for remote validation, the `name` parameter in the `CheckName` method always returns `null`. I have tried including the `Bind` attribute with `Prefix`es such as `Bars` and `Bars[0]` but the `name` parameter is still `null`. Can someone help?

Comment: I have previously reported reported this as a bug on Codeplex (refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models/27517407#27517407](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models/27517407#27517407))

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using the `BindAttribute`:

```
public class FooController
{
     public ActionResult Edit()
     {
          var viewModel = new FooViewModel
          { 
              Bars = new List<BarViewModel> { new BarViewModel() } 
          };
          return View(viewModel);
     }

     // For remote validation
     public ActionResult CheckName([Bind(Prefix = "Bars[0].Name")] string name)
     {
          // Perform remote validation
     }
}
```