# MVC4 Remote Validation Not Receiving Parameter Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validation-engine

I'm trying to implement Remote Validation for a field in a view. Everything so far is working except the parameter in the validation controller method is null even though the field contains a value. What did I miss?

Validation Controller Method

```
public JsonResult IsVanityURL_Available(string VanityURL)
{
    if (!_webSiteInfoRepository.GetVanityURL(VanityURL))
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    string suggestedUID = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} is not available.", VanityURL);

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        string altCandidate = VanityURL + i.ToString();
        if (_webSiteInfoRepository.GetVanityURL(altCandidate)) continue;
        suggestedUID = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} is not available. Try {1}.", VanityURL, altCandidate);
        break;
    }
    return Json(suggestedUID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Entity Property

```
[DisplayName("Vanity URL")]
[Remote("IsVanityURL_Available", "Validation")]
[RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
[Editable(true)]               
public string VanityURL { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedContact.WebSiteInfoes[0].VanityURL)
        </div>
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-small">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-external-link-square fa-fw"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedContact.WebSiteInfoes[0].VanityURL, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Vanity URL" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE 
The answer in the duplicate post does fix the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote Validation for LIST of MODELs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Stephen. I changed the jquery.validate file with the suggested change and it didn't change anything. The parameter is still null.

Comment: Use your browser tools to put a breakpoint on the js file and check that the value of `data` is in fact `{ VanityURL: someValue }`

Comment: Sorry, It did fix the problem. My BundleConfig was using the min version that I didn't change. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate way to avoid changing the jquery.validate.js file. This involved setting the name of the TextBoxFor in the view like so...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedContact.WebSiteInfoes[0].VanityURL, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Vanity URL", @Name="VanityUrl })
```

I reverted my js file change, then added a combination of the view name attribute and the model remote AdditionalFields definition and it worked just fine.

This change caused some unforeseen problems as well. I finally did get a solution. I changed the GET to a POST and grabbed the values I needed from the FormsCollection. This [link](http://crea8ivecode.net/weblog/index.php/remote-validation-in-mvc3-simple-way-to-pass-the-form-value-from-custom-view-model-to-controller-via-remote-attribute/) got me going in the right direction. This allowed me to completely bypass the Complex Data Object naming problem

Answer (score -1):

```
        change your entity 
        [DisplayName("Vanity URL")]
        [Remote("IsVanityURL_Available", "Validation",AdditionalFields = "VanityURL")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
        [Editable(true)]               
        public string VanityURL { get; set; }

    and add this to your view
    @{
    var VanityURL=Model.SelectedContact.WebSiteInfoes[0].VanityURL
    }



<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedContact.WebSiteInfoes[0].VanityURL)
        </div>
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-small">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-external-link-square fa-fw"></i></span>
    @Html.TextBox("VanityURL",VanityURL,new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Vanity URL" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried that and had no success. The value was still null.

Comment: please post your whole entity

Comment: lets see this updated answer is working for you or not