# Remote Attribute doesn't work in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need to make my own validate function, and i found this: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-remote-validation-for-multiple-fields-with-additionalfields-property

I was trying to use Remote Attribute, however chrome doesn't send any information to my JsonResult Method and i don't know why.

My ViewModel:

```
 [Remote("Divisibility", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Value is incorrect.")]
 public int Amount { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.FirstSetList.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success" />
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Divisibility(int Amount)
{
    var value = User.Identity.GetUserId().Where(x => x.Equals("qqqqq"));
    //I know that this condition does not make sense, but this was only for test.
    //Anyway like i said, chrome doesn't send anything to this method.

    return Json(value == null);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Is not the same question as here [Remote Validation for LIST of MODELs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models)
**My Remote Attribute, doesn't send any information to my JsonResult Method**, not null, not 0 just nothing! Never reach breakpoint in this method. Also in NETWORK CONSOLE in chrome there aren't any traffic. It looks like AJAX doesn't work in this case and i don't know why?

Comment: try ``int Amount``

Comment: can you check on console if using chrome, and if firefox firebug console, to see if it is passing value?

Comment: Nothing, just empty.

Comment: you cannot see the ajax request going when you type in textbox?

Comment: Exactly, nothing in Network console (Chrome)

Comment: Is it working on other browser? Which browser?

Comment: No. It doesn't work.

Comment: Try removing `, "Account"` part win your attribute. Just keep it `[Remote("Divisibility".......` rest as is.

Comment: Error: 
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A route named 'Divisibility' could not be found in the route collection.

Comment: @DiPix, It is a duplicate because if it hits your controller method, then it would never work. But if you not even hitting your controller method then you have other problems as well (have you included `jquery-{version}.js`? what errors do you get in the console?)

Comment: Yes i've got jquery (Bundle). The problem is there ain't any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your hole model to your JsonResult Method, like:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Divisibility(ModelName model)
{
    //user your variable name
    model.Value = User.Identity.GetUserId().Where(x => x.Equals("qqqqq"));
    return Json(value == null);
}
```

Or remove the "HttpPost" just to see if now it's passing values:

**Model:**

```
[Remote("Divisibility", "Account", ErrorMessage = "Value is incorrect.")]
 public int Amount { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Divisibility(int Amount)
{
    var value = User.Identity.GetUserId().Where(x => x.Equals("qqqqq"));

    return Json(value == null);
}
```

Comment: Nothing, in both case Network console in chrome is just empty.