# Asp.net MVC: Additional fields are not binding for Remote validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, remote-validation

I have list of models and want to perform remote validation.

Model:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("Method", "Controller", HttpMethod = "POST", AdditionalFields = "prop2,prop3", ErrorMessage = "Error")]
 public string prop1 { get; set; }
```

The name generated by MVC for each elements are like below:

```
<input type='text' name='test[0].prop1' />
```

Because of this, values are not binding to the parameters. I took help from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models). Now I am getting the value for 'prop1' but still 'prop2' and 'prop3' are not getting bound.

Edit: I am using [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem) to render the list elements.

Any help or suggestion would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have as parameter for the remote `POST` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27517407/4811951) and fixed it by modifying the `remote method` in `jquery-validate.js` file as below:

```
remote: function(value, element, param) {
 ....
  param = typeof param === "string" && {url:param} || param;
  ....

  for (var property in param.data) {
    if (param.data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        param.data[property.substr(property.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)] = param.data[property];
      }
    }
   //ajax call
```

Answer (score 2):

If the remote method takes an object (as parameter) that holds its sub-items, they should be mapped automatically, for instance:

```cs
public class Stuff
{
  public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
  [Remote(action:"Validate", controller: "Account", 
      HttpMethod = "POST", 
      ErrorMessage = "Error",
      AdditionalFields = "Prop2,Prop3")]
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }

  public string Prop2 { get; set; }
  public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

```cshtml
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account"))
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Items[i].Prop1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Items[i].Prop2)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Items[i].Prop3)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it help? Please let me know.

Comment: No it doesn't. I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem to render the list elements. That's why your answer is not helping. Please let me know if there is any other way

Comment: And you didn't mention what custom model binder you were using, until just now. That's why it's hard to tell. Thanks for letting us know anyway.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for inconvenience caused

Answer (score 0):

By default all model properties are null except main property,

If you have another propeties to validate Bind Include them.

```
public ActionResult CheckThings([Bind(Include = "prop2,prop3")] Model model)
{
.....
}
```

If your action method dosnt accept model and you pass seperated fields to it, use

```
public ActionResult CheckThings([Bind(Prefix = "Prop1OrSomethigElse")]string prop1, [Bind(Prefix = "Prop2OrSomethigElse")]string prop2, [Bind(Prefix = "Prop3OrSomethigElse")]string prop3)
{
.....
}
```

Comment: How can I specify test[0] as Prefix?