# Multiple validations based on RadioButton selection?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am currently trying to validate a text field in my MVC View to meet multiple criteria.

- Overall, the field must not be null.
- There will be a radio button group that has option `A` or `B`. If `A` is chosen, I will need to make sure that what was entered is a valid entry in the dataset I am comparing it against. If `B` is chosen, then I do not need to perform this validation.

I already have the validation in place for preventing the text field from being null, as well as validating what was entered with what is in the data set. I am trying to add the RadioButtons.

Currently I am validating my form with `DataAnnotations`. Currently I am always validating the text field by using a remote validator. Heres my entry in my view model.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
[Remote ("ControllerMethod", "Controller", ErrorMessage = "{0} is not a in the data set.")]
[Display(Name = "Account")] 
public string Account { get; set; }
```

What I am unsure on how to do is add another level of validation based on what is selected in in the RadioButton.

Comment: Probably not the best idea, but certainly one of the more simple would be to create partial views that have specific validation models which are loaded into your HTML via AJAX when you select an option on your radio button list. Alternatively, you can use JavaScript events to add/remove your validation attributes from the element based on the selected radio button.

Comment: @Sippy, I thought about removing the validation attributes if `B` was selected, but wasn't sure if there was a utility out there that I was unaware of.

Comment: You might be able to use the library itself to do that, not sure. The problem you will have is adding them again if they re-select `A` :) to get around that, the best thing I can think of is defining validation rules in JavaScript in the view itself using the library, instead of using data attributes. If you use data attributes then I can't think of a way to carry the validation rules over, though it may well already be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `AdditionalFields` property of `[Remote]` attribute, to pass the value of the selected radio button to the controller. Assuming the name of the property your binding the radio buttons is named `Option`, then

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
[Remote ("ControllerMethod", "Controller", AdditionalFields = "Option", ErrorMessage = "{0} is not a in the data set.")]
[Display(Name = "Account")] 
public string Account { get; set; }
```

and modify the controller method to accept the value of `Account` and `Option`

```
public ActionResult ControllerMethod(string account, string option)
{
  if (option == "B")
  {
    return true; // ignore it and indicate success
  }
  else
  {
    // call service to validate and return result
  }
}
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of an aditional field. This is exactly what I am looking for, but it looks like the additional field is bugged when it comes to radio buttons. I will have to find a work around for that. Thank you though!

Comment: I know - I was the one who reported it as a result of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308852/mvc-remote-validation-with-additional-bool-fields/26309626#26309626). It has been fixed (refer [CodePlex Issue](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2155)) so you will need the latest jquery version.